# Set column in data frame to value when string is found in separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using pandas module in python . I have table x with columns a,b,c similar to as follows:

```
a  b  c
z  4  ''
s  5  ''
u  4  ''
y  3  ''
```

I need to loop through column `a` and search for `"z"`. when `"z"` is found I need `c` to be set to `"123"` until `"y"` is found in column `a` and then `c` needs to be set to `"321"`.

The data will not remain constant in first column so indexes will not work. I have tried many things and cant seem to find a solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: I recommend you accept Wen's answer instead of mine, both Bharath and I went for something too complicated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice the difference between `replace` and `map`:

`map` will return no match item as `NaN`. Later `ffill` will fill the `NaN` from previous row's data.

```
df.assign(c=df.a.map({'z':'123','y':'321'}).ffill())

   a  b    c
0  z  4  123
1  s  5  123
2  u  4  123
3  y  3  321
```

Answer (score 2):

Numpy `where` based approach

```
df['n'] = np.where((df['a'].isin(['z','y']),df['a'],np.nan)
df['n'] = df['n'].ffill()
df['c'] = np.where(df['n'] == 'z' , 123,321)
df.drop('n',1,inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c
0  z  4  123
1  s  5  123
2  u  4  123
3  y  3  321
```

Comment: do this `df.assign(c=df.a.map({'z':'123','y':'321'}).ffill())`

Comment: Your guys answer just confused me ...LOL, I thought I am wrong with this simple one line solution ..

Comment: @Wen you would have got lot votes for that if you posted that as an answer  :) :)

Comment: @Wen you should care about helping future visitors... :)

Comment: @IanS as long as Bharath shetty, already updated, I do not think it is need to open an answer for this :)

Comment: I will rollback if you post that as an answer

Answer (score 2):

Replace all non-y or z values by NaN:

```
df['c'] = df['a'].where(df['a'].isin(['y', 'z']))
```

Forward fill:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].ffill()
```

Replace:

```
df['c'] = df['c'].map({'y': '321', 'z': '123'})
```

Comment: @Bharathshetty in space *and* in time :D

Comment: They're the same really but thanks :) Edit: +1 back!