# Get lowest value after groupby - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with the following format:

```
data = {'City' : ['London', 'Paris', 'Paris','NY' 'London'], 'Distance' : [5, 1, 7, 2, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

    City    Distance
0   London  5
1   Paris   1
2   Paris   7
3   NY      2
4   London  6
```

I want to create a table with all rows with a unique 'City', and whenever there are 2 or more rows with the same 'City' value, I would like it to return the one with the lowest 'Distance'.
So in this case I wanted a table like this:

```
City    Distance
London  5
Paris   1
NY      2
```

I know I can use:

```
df.groupby('City')
```

But I don't know what to add to it to return the smallest 'Distance'.

Best,
Rosa

Comment: only need `idxmin` ;)

Comment: You need `df.loc[df.groupby('City')['Distance'].idxmin()]`

Comment: I cannot find exact dupe, so create answer...

Comment: @jezrael Here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394476/keep-other-columns-when-using-min-with-groupby

Comment: I reopen, so cannot close as dupe...

Comment: Duplicate: [Keep other columns when using min() with groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394476/keep-other-columns-when-using-min-with-groupby)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmin.html) for indexes of minimal `Distance` per group and then select rows by `loc`:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('City', sort=False)['Distance'].idxmin()]
print (df1)
     City  Distance
0  London         5
1   Paris         1
3      NY         2
```

Detail:

```
print (df.groupby('City', sort=False)['Distance'].idxmin())
City
London    0
Paris     1
NY        3
Name: Distance, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I have a similar problem but I would like to find the minimum that is not equal to 0 and have two columns instead of 1.

Comment: @Geosphere - Not sure if understand, can you create new question with sample data, expected output and what you try?

Comment: Yes. I have 3 columns in a dataframe: x, y, time. What I want to retrieve is the row that has the minimum time but the time should be greater than 0 because in that case the x, y have the same value.

Comment: I have tried using df.min() but kept getting a series instead and I want the row. I also tried df['time'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1) but I'm still getting the 0.0 as lowest value.

Comment: @Geosphere - Can you create new question? be free modify `df = pd.DataFrame({'City' : ['London', 'Paris', 'Paris','NY' 'London'], 'Distance' : [5, 1, 7, 2, 6]})` and add expected output - create answer from your comments :)

Comment: Another question on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @Geosphere - Yes, try create new one :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49469300/pandas-dataframe-find-the-row-with-minimum-value-based-on-two-columns-but-grea

Comment: When I run this, I get a future warning: `Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing label will raise KeyError in the future, you can use .reindex() as an alternative`. Is this an issue that we will have to worry about?

Answer (score 5):

Sometime `groupby` is  unnecessary, try  `drop_duplicates`

```
df.sort_values('Distance').drop_duplicates('City')

Out[377]: 
     City  Distance
0  London         5
1   Paris         1
3      NY         2
```

Comment: It is my opinion that this approach should be quick.  Also, it is unnecessary to include `'City'` in the sort.  And if you leave it out, you don't need the other `sort_index`.  `df.sort_values('City').drop_duplicates('City') `

Comment: I like your solution. Reminds me of [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46490720/5276797) we had :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
>>> df.groupby(['City'], sort=False)['Distance'].min()
City
London    5
Paris     1
NY        2
Name: Distance, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem expressed in the OP.  The question clearly asks to return the rows for which the minimum resides, for each group.  This will always return a series with unique cities in the index and the corresponding minimum distances.  Any other columns would be lost.

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that @jezrael offers the most idiomatic approach within a `groupby`.  I've offered the same solution myself on other answers.  However, here are some other alternatives.

**Option 1**
Use `pd.DataFrame.nsmallest` within an `apply`
This offers clean logic even if the api is a bit clumsy.  I think this version of `nsmallest` should be available to the `groupby` object.  But as of pandas 0.20.3, it is not.  So we use it within the general purpose `apply` method.  Make sure to use `group_keys=False` in the call to `groupby` in order to avoid awkward additional indices.

```
df.groupby('City', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.nsmallest(1, columns='Distance'))

     City  Distance
0  London         5
3      NY         2
1   Paris         1
```

---

**Option 2**
Was taken by @Wen so I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It´s an old question but for the sake of completion:

```
df.sort_values(by=['Distance'], ascending=True).groupby('City').first().reset_index(drop=False)
```

provides the same output.