# Pandas Dataframe - find the row with minimum value based on two columns but greater than 0

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: x, y, time. There are a few thousand rows.

What I want to do is retrieve the row with the minimum time but I would like that the minimum should not be 0.

e.g.

```
x     y    time
240   1    28.5
240   2    19.3
240   240     0
240   19    9.7
```

So far what I've tried were the following:

```
df.loc[df['time'] > 0].min()
# this gives me a series and I want a row
# x    225.000000
# y      0.000000
# time   1.066606

df['time'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(1)
# 225    0.0
```

I have also tried something with groupby as well

```
df.loc[df.groupby('id_x', sort=False)['time'].idxmin()]
```

I know had problems subsetting this one as I usually got a series.

Comment: Thank you for all the help guys! That was extremely fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can filter out `0` values by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and get index of minimal value by [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html), last select by `loc`:

```
s = df.loc[df.query('time != 0')['time'].idxmin()]
print (s)
x       240.0
y        19.0
time      9.7
Name: 3, dtype: float64

df = df.loc[[df.query('time != 0')['time'].idxmin()]]
print (df)
     x   y  time
3  240  19   9.7
```

Comment: @Geosphere - I check your question again and remove `groupby` solution, because here is better one :)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
In [69]: df.loc[df.time>0, 'time'].idxmin()
Out[69]: 3
```

or

```
In [72]: df.loc[[df.loc[df.time>0, 'time'].idxmin()]]
Out[72]:
     x   y  time
3  240  19   9.7
```

Comment: That worked as well, the second one was what I wanted, the first option I believe gave me the location/index of that row.

Comment: @Geosphere Don't use groupby. This solution is really the best.

Comment: Indeed, groupby was not necessary. It only made matters more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `groupby` at all. Here's an option with `mask`/`where` + `loc` + `idxmin`;

```
df.loc[[df.time.mask(df.time.eq(0)).idxmin()]]
```

Or,

```
df.loc[[df.time.where(df.time.ne(0)).idxmin()]]
```

```
     x   y  time
3  240  19   9.7
```

Comment: The thing is I wanted to retrieve a row, not a series. But it did gave me an accurate answer compared to my previous attempts where I got the answer wrong. I haven't tried using mask before, so interesting solution. thanks!