# Lookup smallest value greater than current

Tags: pandas

I have an `objects` table and a `lookup` table. In the `objects` table, I'm looking to add the smallest value from the `lookup` table that is greater than the object's `number`.

I found this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49469300/3346095) but it's about finding a value greater than a constant, rather than changing for each row.

In code:

```
import pandas as pd

objects = pd.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "number": 10}, {"id": 2, "number": 30}])

lookup = pd.DataFrame([{"number": 3}, {"number": 12}, {"number": 40}])

expected = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        {"id": 1, "number": 10, "smallest_greater": 12},
        {"id": 2, "number": 30, "smallest_greater": 40},
    ]
)
```

Comment: What is happens if value not exist?

Comment: I think if not exist `smallest_greater` value per row

Comment: @jezrael You mean in the case of object `{'id': 3, 'number': 100}`, because there is no number >100 in `lookup`? In that case `None`.

Comment: yes, exactly. give me some time for add it to my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First compare each value `lookup['number']` by `objects['number']` to 2d boolean mask, then add `cumsum` and compare first value by `1` and get position by [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) for set value by `lookup['number']`.

Output is generated with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for overwrite all not matched values to `NaN`.

```
objects = pd.DataFrame([{"id": 1, "number": 10}, {"id": 2, "number": 30},
                        {"id": 3, "number": 100},{"id": 4, "number": 1}])

print (objects)
   id  number
0   1      10
1   2      30
2   3     100
3   4       1

m1 = lookup['number'].values >= objects['number'].values[:, None]
m2 = np.cumsum(m1, axis=1) == 1
m3 = np.any(m1, axis=1)
out = lookup['number'].values[m2.argmax(axis=1)]

objects['smallest_greater'] = np.where(m3, out, np.nan)
print (objects)
   id  number  smallest_greater
0   1      10              12.0
1   2      30              40.0
2   3     100               NaN
3   4       1               3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

smallest_greater = []
for i in objects['number']:         smallest_greater.append(lookup['number'[lookup[lookup['number']>i].sort_values(by='number').index[0]])
objects['smallest_greater'] = smallest_greater