# Getting index value in pandas multiindex based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have created a dataframe with this code:
The objective of this is to find the weekly low and to get the dates date at which the weekly low took place.
To do this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import pandas_datareader
import datetime

df = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
df2 = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start, end)
start = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)
end = datetime.datetime.today()

df['Date1'] = df.index

df['month'] = df.index.month
df['week'] = df.index.week
df['day'] = df.index.day
df.set_index('week',append=True,inplace=True)
df.set_index('day',append=True,inplace=True)
```

To get the weekly low :

```
df['Low'].groupby(['week']).min().tail(50)
```

[image]

I trying to find out the date on which weekly low occured: Such as 1735.420044

If i try to do this :

```
df['Low'].isin([1735.420044])
```

I get :

```
Date        week  day
2020-12-31  53    31     False
2021-01-04  1     4      False
2021-01-05  1     5      False
2021-01-06  1     6      False
2021-01-07  1     7      False
                         ...  
2021-08-02  31    2      False
2021-08-03  31    3      False
2021-08-04  31    4      False
2021-08-05  31    5      False
2021-08-06  31    6      False
Name: Low, Length: 151, dtype: bool
```

How can i get the actual dates for the low?

Comment: Use [`df['Low'].idxmin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) - this will return the index of label(s) of the minimum value.

Comment: I am trying to get the dates where weekly lows. Thats why i had multi-indexed it to get the value of each week.

Comment: you can always group by week and then use idxmin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get lowest value after groupby - Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46587018/get-lowest-value-after-groupby-pandas)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the weekly lows, you could simply access the index.

```
res = df['Low'].groupby(['week']).min()
```

`res` is the series of lowest prices with the date in the index.  You can access the raw numpy array that represents the index with `res.index.values`.  This will include `week` and `day` levels as well.

To get just the dates as a series, this should work:

```
dates = res.index.get_level_values("Date").to_series()
```

**PS:** Clarification from the comments

```
df['Low'].isin([1735.420044]).any() # returns False
```

The above doesn't work for you (should return `True` if there's a match) because when you say `.isin([<bunch of floats>])`, you are essentially comparing floats for equality.  Which doesn't work because floating point comparisons can never be guaranteed to be exact, they always have to be in ranges of tolerance (this is not Python specific, true for all languages).  Sometimes it might seem to work in Python, but that is entirely coincidental and is a result of underlying memory optimisations.  Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595425/what-is-the-best-way-to-compare-floats-for-almost-equality-in-python) to gain some (Python specific) insight into this.

Comment: I initially tried that but that is just giving me an empty dataframe

Comment: @Slartibartfast Then you do not have a match, you can check with `df['Low'].isin([1735.420044]).any()`. If that returns `False`, there are no matches, maybe because you are trying to compare floats.  Exact comparisons of floating point numbers are unpredictable and are never recommended.

Comment: it returns `False` but how is it possible when we can see it in the dataframe?

Comment: You cannot do exact comparisons with floating point numbers,

Comment: So i cannot do something like this? `df.where(df['Low'].groupby(['week']).min())`

Comment: @Slartibartfast does my revised answer help you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235767/discussion-between-suvayu-and-slartibartfast).